# CasperJS: swallows special keys like Enter?

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I'm trying to write a test using CasperJS for a scenario where pressing Enter in an input is the trigger for the page to do something with the text otherwise typed into the input.

An abbreviated/simplified version of the CasperJS test:

```
casper.start('http://localhost:3000/input-demo', function() {
  this.sendKeys('#demo-input', 'demo text');
  this.sendKeys('#demo-input', '\uE007');
  this.test.assertEquals(this.getHTML('#stage'), 'input demo');
});

casper.run();
```

(Where we run it as `casperjs test this-test.js`)

I've verified that `sendKeys` is getting the text into the input, but that text never shows up in the `#stage` element. A "vanilla" PhantomJS implementation of the keypress works fine, where `webpage.sendEvent('keypress', '\uE007')` causes the on-page event handler to fire. Looking at the source of `casper.sendKeys`, I see that it is delegating to the `sendEvent` on the Casper instance's PhantomJS instance (i.e., [line 1613 in the current version of casper.js](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/blob/2bc03233ab1547a975f95015827699af7568ec1d/modules/casper.js#L1613)).

Any ideas? Anyone gotten these keys to work in a CasperJS test?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You might want to add {keepFocus: true} to the first sendKeys call. If you see the source code, without adding a keepFocus, it is blurring the text area and that means your second sendKeys call will not accept the keypress.

This seems to work.

```
casper.start('http://localhost:3000/input-demo', function() {
  this.sendKeys('#demo-input', 'demo text', {keepFocus: true});
  this.sendKeys('#demo-input', casper.page.event.key.Enter , {keepFocus: true});
  this.test.assertEquals(this.getHTML('#stage'), 'input demo');
});

casper.run();
```

Comment: For a list of special keys available in casper.page.event.key see: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/commit/cab2635e66d74b7e665c44400b8b20a8f225153a