# How fill a search field with CasperJS

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs, web-crawler, casperjs

I need to put "75018" in search field  in [this site](http://www.chronodrive.com/) and click on search button with **CasperJS**.
i [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18676549/how-to-login-by-filling-the-form-in-casperjs) question, and follow the instruction, i get a screenshot for debuging, but it doesnt click in button.

i tried this

```
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;

var casper = require('casper').create({
        clientScripts:  [
        'jquery-1.10.1.min.js'
        ],
        pageSettings: {
        loadImages:  true,     
        loadPlugins: true,
        userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.2 Safari/537.36',
        webSecurityEnabled: false,
        ignoreSslErrors: false,
        sslProtocol: "tlsv1"
    },
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: 'warning'
//    logLevel: 'debug'
});

var utils = require('utils');
var fs = require('fs');
var system = require('system');

casper.options.viewportSize = {width: 1920, height: 1080};
var counter = 0;
var dejaexclu = false;    

function getData(filepath){

  var eol = system.os.name == 'windows' ? "\r\n" : "\n";
  var data = fs.read(filepath);
  //utils.dump(data);
  var arrdata = data.split(eol);
  //utils.dump(arrdata);
  return arrdata;
}

function count(){
  counter = counter +1;
  return counter;
}

casper.start('http://www.chronodrive.com', function() {
   console.log("page loaded");
   this.test.assertExists('form#searchShopForm', 'form is found');
   this.fill('form#searchShopForm', { 
        searchField: '75018'
    }, true);
});
casper.then(function() {
  console.log("photo");

      console.log("photo");
        this.click('#blinksubmit');
        this.captureSelector("screenshot.png", "html");
           console.log("photo"); 
});
casper.run();
```

my screen shot that shows i can put the value in field but it doesnt click

[image]

Comment: Please add the markup of the input field to your question. You can remove the screenshot.

Comment: @ArtjomB. i don't know how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Try this instead</strike>

```
this.fillSelectors('form#searchShopForm', { 
        "input[id='searchField']" : "75018"
    }, true);
```

See http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#fillselectors

or put quotes around your searchField

e.g.

```
'searchField' : '75018'
```

see http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#fill

Ah sorry, I see this is an auto suggest and doesn't have the concept of a button to submit. Therefore change the true to false and then try to use sendkeys to send the enter key e.g.

[CasperJS: swallows special keys like Enter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21843958/casperjs-swallows-special-keys-like-enter)

**Edit**

This code works the issue isn't with casper it is with the search box and animation. That is things take some time to show. The **golden** rule of thumb with casper is everytime you ask for a new resource/page/script/html/json then its a good idea to use a **casper.waitForXXX** this allows for the time it takes to wait for the server or for animations etc.

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    viewportSize : {width: 1920, height: 1080}
});


casper.start('http://www.chronodrive.com/prehome');

casper.waitForText("Pour toutes", function() {

    this.sendKeys('#searchField', '06150 bordeaux', {keepFocus: true});
    this.sendKeys('#searchField', casper.page.event.key.Enter , {keepFocus: true});

});

casper.waitForText("Cannes", function() {
    casper.capture('tmp.jpg');
});

casper.run();
```

[image]

Comment: like you see in my screenshot, i can fill the field by 75018, i just can't click on "chercher" buttom,

Comment: Thanks for your edition, i tired it, but i have the same result.